# Ansible throwing error on nested looping - counter issue

Tags: ansible

We are trying to use a nested loop in shell commmand. The counter part (Looping from 0 to 5) is not getting substituted on the line and due to which ansible is throwing error.

Task is as below

```
- name: debug
  debug: var=output.results.{{item}}.stdout.split('|').1
  with_items:
    - 0
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - 4
    - 5

- name: Remove Groups
  shell: echo neutron port-update {{ output.results.{{item}}.stdout.split("|").1 }} --no-security-groups > /tmp/test.txt
  with_items:
    - 0
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - 4
    - 5
```

Just to show the debug output

```
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=2.2.2.2)
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=3.3.3.3)
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=4.4.4.4)
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=5.5.5.5)
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=6.6.6.6)
changed: [1.1.1.1] => (item=7.7.7.7)
```

when we give the task as

```
output.results.0.stdout.split('|').1
or 
output.results.1.stdout.split('|').1
```

we are getting the corrspondin IP .

But when we loop it for 5 times, items are not getting substtituted resulting in the following error

```
fatal: [1.1.1.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: echo neutron port-update {{ output.results.[item].stdout.split(\"|\").1 }} --no-security-groups > /tmp/test.txt"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` part already is interpreted as a jinja variable/expression. Therefore you can not place a variable with curly braces inside. Also you can not nest expressions in each other. `{{ foo {{ bar }} }}` is invalid syntax.

This should work:

```
debug: msg="{{ output.results[item].stdout.split('|').1 }}"
...
shell: echo neutron port-update {{ output.results[item].stdout.split("|").1 }} --no-security-groups > /tmp/test.txt
```